# Failed to use IDA to remote android debug

Tags: ida

I use 32-bit IDA to debug, but an error occurs.

IDA error message:

```
Incompatible debugging server:debugger id is 1 expected 11(armlinux)
```

cmd details:

```
  root@android:/ # /data/local/tmp/android_x86_server 
  IDA Android x86 32-bit remote debug server(ST) v1.22. Hex-Rays (c) 2004-2017 
  Listening on 0.0.0.0:23946...
> ========================================================= 
  [1] Accepting connection from 127.0.0.1... 
  [1] Incompatible IDA version
> [1] Closing connection from 127.0.0.1...
```

IDA Pro version: 7.0

Answer (score 1):

You need to select `Remote Linux` in the debugger attach menu of IDA. We are using x86 emulator, not ARM CPU. Just worked this out myself by accident.